# conda installed but conda env create not found

Tags: python, conda

Typing

`Conda`

in the command line works as expected but

`conda env create -f environment.yml`

causes my shell to output

`CommandNotFoundError: No command 'conda env'`

I'm wondering if anyone knows what's up or how I fix this?

Running

`conda update conda` as suggested in the comment resulted in the following:

```
PackageNotInstalledError: Package is not installed in prefix.
prefix: /usr
package name: conda
```

Comment: Try `conda update conda` first.

Comment: I've updated it

Comment: Open in a new terminal and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Your PATH environment variable may be pointing to the wrong prefix. Try `which conda` first, then change or add the PATH in your .bash_profile.

You may also need to track it down and then run it with a qualified path to the `conda` command, or add the `bin` directory inside of the Anaconda installation to your `$PATH`.